# Tableviewcell image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimage

```
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,145,20)];
img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dollor.png"];

[cell.contentView addSubview:img];
[img release];
```

Is this code right????
Please help
I'm trying to place an image in the tableviewcell

Comment: [cell addSubview:] also works but are you sure your frame origin is correct??

Comment: yes its correct  but your code is not working

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dollor.png"];
```

nothing else.

Comment: Please check the image name as it is case sensitive too.. otherwise the syntax works fine for me. Other than that what is the problem, you are facing with the code .

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(5,5,145,25);

cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dollor.png"];
```